# Converting rails query from Mysql to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

Can anyone tell me how to convert this query to PostgreSQL

routes_controller.rb

```
@routes = Route.joins([:departure_location, :destination_location]).where("mdm_locations.name like ? or destination_locations_mdm_routes.name like ?" , "%#{k}%", "%#{k}%")
```

routes.rb (model)

```
module Mdm

  class Route < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :uom
    belongs_to :distance_uom, :class_name => "Uom", :foreign_key => "distance_uom_id"
    belongs_to :location
    belongs_to :departure_location, :class_name => "Location", :foreign_key => "departure"
    belongs_to :destination_location, :class_name => "Location", :foreign_key => "destination"

    has_many :voyages, :dependent => :restrict

    attr_accessible :description, :distance, :distance_uom_id, :departure, :std_consm, :destination, :uom_id

    validates_presence_of :departure, :destination
 end
end



Error :
PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...NNER JOIN "mdm_locations" ON "mdm_locations"."id" = "mdm_rou...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mdm_routes" INNER JOIN "mdm_locations" ON "mdm_locations"."id" = "mdm_routes"."departure" INNER JOIN "mdm_locations" "destination_locations_mdm_routes" ON "destination_locations_mdm_routes"."id" = "mdm_routes"."destination" WHERE (LOWER(mdm_locations.name) like '%futong%' or LOWER(destination_locations_mdm_routes.name) like '%futong%')
```

Comment: i try to this query         @routes = Route.joins([:departure_location, :destination_location]).where("LOWER(mdm_locations.name) like ? or LOWER(destination_locations_mdm_routes.name) like ?", "%#{k.downcase}%", "%#{k.downcase}%")

but i get error 
PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = character varying
LINE 1: ...NNER JOIN "mdm_locations" ON "mdm_locations"."id" = "mdm_rou...

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely edit the question and post the full error.  You ran out of characters on your comment and we can't see the entire error.

Comment: i have edit my question so what happen here and how to convert it, 'cause in mysql it's okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message says:

> operator does not exist: integer = character varying

and points you at this part of the SQL:

```
INNER JOIN "mdm_locations" ON "mdm_locations"."id" = "mdm_routes"."departure"
-- ------------------------------------------------^
```

Combining those tells us that `mdnm_locations.id` is an integer (as expected) but `mdm_routes.departure` is a `varchar`. You can't compare integers and strings in SQL without explicitly casting one of them to make the types compatible.

You need to fix your schema, `mdm_routes.departure` should be an integer column, not a string.

MySQL tries to be friendly by attempting to guess your intent and lets you get away with a lot of sloppy practices. PostgreSQL tries to be friendly by forcing you to say exactly what you mean to avoid confusions, incorrect guesses, and hidden bugs.